# Strange decoding after using split function of python( eg: \x00)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

This was a very strange situation, the split function is changing string format.
Please look at the below code,

**Code:**

```
COM_Port = serial.Serial(COM_PortName)
with COM_Port as port:
    while True:
         RxedData = port.readline()
         line = RxedData.decode('utf-8')
         print("Line 1: ", line)
         row = line.split(',')[1:-1]
         print("Line 2: ", row)
```

**Output:**

```
Line 1: "* , 0 0 0 0 0 5 7 5 , 2 3 : 0 3 : 4 7 , 1 1 / 0 2 / 2 0 , 1 2 . 3 4 5 , K P A , 0 0 0 0 6 . 8 3 , S L P M , T B ,                 , $ "

Line 2: ['\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x006\x002\x001\x00', '\x002\x000\x00:\x004\x006\x00:\x005\x001\x00', '\x001\x002\x00/\x000\x002\x00/\x002\x000\x00', '\x001\x002\x00.\x003\x004\x005\x00', '\x00K\x00P\x00A\x00', '\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x00.\x000\x000\x00', '\x00C\x00C\x00P\x00M\x00', '\x00T\x00G\x00', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

How the `Line 2`, get into `\x000\x000...`? What is this encoding format? How to get it into the right format?

**Edit 1:**

```
print([hex(i) for i in RxedData])
```

**Output:**

```
['0x2a', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x3a', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x3a', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x33', '0x0', '0x2f', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x2f', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x2e', '0x0', '0x33', '0x0', '0x34', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x4b', '0x0', '0x50', '0x0', '0x41', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x33', '0x0', '0x34', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x2e', '0x0', '0x36', '0x0', '0x36', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x53', '0x0', '0x4c', '0x0', '0x50', '0x0', '0x48', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x24', '0x0', '0xa']
```

Comment: `\x00` is the way to notate the ASCII null character, which is what I assume is happening here. I don't know why `Line 1` and `Line 2` would print differently, though.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy What is the best practice to decode `ASCII` string?

Comment: To clarify, internally `\x00` should render as a single null character, the same as `\n` renders internally as just one character.

Comment: The two lines are printing differently because you're printing different things. On `Line 1`, you're printing a string directly, so the `print` function (or maybe the console itself, not sure) are able to display the ascii bytes as their characters. On `Line 2`, you're now printing a list, so the byte interpretation doesn't happen during the `print`.

Comment: @b_c Thanks for explaining. How to make it interprets correctly? Do I need to use any decoding on the elements of the list? Can you please help? these lines are printed on idle.

Comment: You should try to provide an hexdump of `RxedData` so that we could be able to reproduce. Could you add `print([hex(i) for i in RxedData])`?

Comment: @SergeBallest I have updated the Hexdump of RxedData in my edit.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, from the hexdump of the recieved bytes, it appears that each *ASCII* character is followed with a NULL byte (`\x00`). That is just the UTF-16-LE representation of the characters. The UTF-8 decode just keeps the code points of the initial bytes because all are below 128, leaving all the interleaving nulls. And you cannot simply decode the byte string as UTF-16 (what it is indeed) because you got it through a `readline` which just stopped after the newline character and has not read the following null one.

If you could read another line, it would probably start with that null character, making the line appearing as UTF-16-BE encoded...

What can be done then?

A trivial workaround is just to get rid of the null characters. If you can be sure that you will only get plain ASCII characters (no accented ones like `é`, no emoticons, no greek or cyrillic ones, etc.), this would be enough:

```
     RxedData = port.readline()
     line = RxedData.replace(b'\x00', b'').decode('ascii')
     print("Line 1: ", line)
     row = line.split(',')[1:-1]
     print("Line 2: ", row)
```

With that values: `['0x2a', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x3a', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x3a', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x33', '0x0', '0x2f', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x2f', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x30', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x2e', '0x0', '0x33', '0x0', '0x34', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x4b', '0x0', '0x50', '0x0', '0x41', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x31', '0x0', '0x32', '0x0', '0x33', '0x0', '0x34', '0x0', '0x35', '0x0', '0x2e', '0x0', '0x36', '0x0', '0x36', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x53', '0x0', '0x4c', '0x0', '0x50', '0x0', '0x48', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2d', '0x0', '0x2c', '0x0', '0x24', '0x0', '0xa']`, you should obtain:

```
Line 1:  *,00000001,11:51:50,13/02/20,12.345,KPA,12345.66,SLPH,,--------,$

Line 2:  ['00000001', '11:51:50', '13/02/20', '12.345', 'KPA', '12345.66', 'SLPH', '', '--------']
```

The good point with it is that is simple and robust **provided you only have plain ASCII**

---

The encoding conformant wait would be to use a TextIOWrapper around the serial port, and specify the UTF-16-LE encoding in it. I could not test it (no Serial on my box and no need for it) so only guessing what should be done.

```
COM_Port = serial.Serial(COM_PortName)
with io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(COM_Port, COM_Port), encoding = 'utf-16-le') as port:
    while True:
         line = port.readline()
         print("Line 1: ", line)
         row = line.split(',')[1:-1]
         print("Line 2: ", row)
```

Here, the TextIOWrapper will take care of the null byte following the newline byte, and will give you directly true unicode strings.

Comment: This is some great info! Based on your analysis it appears there's a NULL byte being ignored/truncated at one end of OP's transmission (beginning for `utf-16-be`, end for `utf-16-le`).

Comment: I tried using your code, but somehow it was not able to pass the following line:
`with io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(COM_Port, COM_Port), encoding = 'utf-16-le') as port:`
There were no errors or exceptions, but the flow didn't move forward

Comment: @siddharthkshirsagar: I could no test so problems may still be there. Here I suspect a buffering problem, so I would try to change the `TextIOWrapper` declaration to `io.TextIOWrapper(..., encoding = 'utf-16-le', line_buffering=True)` or even `io.TextIOWrapper(..., encoding = 'utf-16-le', line_buffering=True)` if you want to send not new line terminated commands.

Answer (score 3):

Decided to turn my comment into an answer (mostly so I could include code).

> The two lines are printing differently because you're printing different things. On `Line 1`, you're printing a string directly, so the `print` function (or maybe the console itself, not sure) are able to display the ASCII bytes as their characters. On `Line 2`, you're now printing a list, so the byte interpretation doesn't happen during the `print`.

Your `line` string, after the decode, very likely has `\x00` (NULL) bytes embedded in it instead of ASCII spaces (`\x20`).

```
>>> x = '*\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x005\x007\x005\x00'
>>> print(x)
'* , 0 0 0 0 0 5 7 5 ,'
>>> print(x.split(','))
['*\x00', '\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x005\x007\x005\x00']
```

To amend my quoted comment, this appears to be based on whatever console is printing the characters. I get the above output from cmd and PowerShell, but Jupyter Notebook instead prints this: `*,00000575`. Note the "spaces" are now gone.

If I change a few of the `\x00` bytes to `\x20` instead, Jupyter will then print what you're seeing above (in the positions where they were replaced at least). This is just to show that NULL characters and Space characters can *visually* look identical, depending on the console displaying them.

```
>>> x = '*\x20,\x200\x200\x000\x000\x000\x005\x007\x005\x00'
>>> print(x)
* , 0 0000575
```

Edit for your comment:

> How to make it interprets correctly?

It depends what "correctly" means to you. In essence, everything *has* been interpreted correctly - your serial port is just sending across NULL bytes instead of space characters.

If you would rather have ASCII spaces instead of NULL bytes though, you can do a simple replace on the string (printed from Jupyter, which displays NULLs as nothing). You can also just use `' '` instead of `'\x20'` if you prefer.

```
>>> print(x.replace('\x00', '\x20').split(','))
['* ', ' 0 0 0 0 0 5 7 5 ']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, replacing '\x00' with '' is what finally fixed my issue.